# cooperative game that is NOT like pandemic, forbidden island et al

Tags: recommendations, cooperation

The cooperative games I have played (pandemic, forbidden island, ghost story) share very similar mechanics in which players have to deal with different threats as fast as they can or they loose.

Is there any other good cooperative game without that rush-playing style? I would like to try something that allows players to use more long term and complex strategies.

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic per our [faq].  They don't fit well with the StackExchange format of Q&A and are better suited for a regular forum.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have **[Sherlock Holmes Consulting Detective](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2511/sherlock-holmes-consulting-detective)**, in which the goal is to find the truth in the smallest number of steps. You can never lose to SHCD, you can simple have a very bad score.

In **[Shadows over Camelot](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/15062/shadows-over-camelot)**, each quest will give you either white or black swords. The game ends when the players collected 12 swords or more and they win if more than half of them are white.

And my favourite: **[Les Mousquetaires du Roy](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/78954/mousquetaires-du-roy)** (Ye King's Musketeers) is a semi-cooperative in which a player incarnates Milady, the evil spy of the Cardinal of Richelieu and all the others play Athos, Portos, Aramis, D'Artagnan and/or Tréville. Quests will reward the players but as they don't play against the game but against another player, the game isn't quite like a usual cooperative game.
The game can be a 1-vs-0 up to 5-vs-0 game, or a 1-vs-1 up to 5-vs-1 game.

Comment: Isn't SOC similar to Pandemic/Forbidden Island in the "rush-playing style." There are catapults, attacking hordes, dragons, the grail sinking into dispair...

Comment: Yes, it may be considered as such, but the fact that 1) you can give up quests if you don't mind having some black swords and 2) there might be a traitor, make it different. It's only my personal opinion, not a rule.

Comment: les mousquetaires du roy sounds quite interesting. thanks